# children's short story about boy flying plane in storm

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I am trying to identify and locate a children's short story about a boy who takes over the flying of a plane in a storm when the pilot becomes incapacitated. I am not sure, but I believe the boy was taking lessons and a storm came and the pilot/instructor had a heart attack or something. The boy landed the plane successfully. I had thought the name might be something like "Solo Flight" or "Flying Solo". I had read them to my young daughter in the early 2000's and I thought it might have been from 1940's era readers, but they might also have been from a library book.

Other elements of the story are: They didn't think the student was ready for a solo flight... something related to panic. So there was an "I showed them" moment after his accidental solo flight. The plane was going too fast and was broken in some way, so land successfully, he pulled a fishtail to slow the plane.

The story inspired my daughter to become a pilot when she got older.

Comment: This is a good start, but can you [edit] your question to add a few more details that might help our site users come up with a possible answer? In particular, what country (and, if relevant, what language) was the story *published*, and in what country (if known) was it *set*?

Comment: [Blind Flight](https://www.amazon.com/Blind-Flight-Hilary-Milton/dp/0590321145) by Hilary Milton, perhaps?

Comment: I remember reading this in high school. It was one of the stories in an English literature anthology called Jade, but can't find anything on Google :( I seem to remember also that the boy kept calling "mayday" on the radio